# Help understand, function(e) in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to learn about the `function(e)`, its functions, parameters and similar. Can you point me to some tutorials I can use

Comment: Can you give more context? `function(e)` itself is not related to jQuery, it is just a function signature that takes one parameter. There is no *the* `function(e)`.

Comment: You mean anonymous functions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#JavaScript

Comment: What do you mean? function is a javascript keyword. It isn't jquery specific.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean - If you knew nothing about your problem, would you be able to understand it from what you've written?

Comment: I didn't know that what i a asking was about event handler. :D

Answer (score 3):

You should be more precise. It is mostly used as event object, but what it contains is strictly connected with event type.
Take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 1):

To any event handler in jQuery, the first argument is the event object, normally called `e` or `event`, you can read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

The *most* common uses are using it for stop bubbling ([`e.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)), stopping the default event ([`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)), or  getting/using the target ([`e.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/))
, but there are lots of other uses as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is an anonymous function that takes one named argument: e. (And, like any JS function, any number of unnamed arguments available through the `arguments` array.

It does whatever it is written to do.

In most cases, `e` suggests that it will be used as an event handler, so `e` will be an [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Comment: Are you trying to say that, I can give something like `$("p").click(fucntion(param1,param2) { ............... });`

Comment: That isn't what I was saying, although you could, but the second argument will never be offered a value.